# CSS3 Transform Scaled Image Hidden by div

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, css-transforms, buddypress

I am working on a BuddyPress theme where there will be some images floating right on the padder div using `add_action="bp_before_blog_post"`.  On Linux/Firefox everything works as expected.  The transform expands out and overlaps the sidebar div.

On Chrome and Safari the image expands to the sidebar div but then is hidden.  I have tripple checked BP-Default theme and there isn't a css `overflow: hidden` value for the sidebar, or padder div.  I have checked every line of bp-default.css, and used Chrome Web Developer and Firebug to check the live css.

I can't try a `position:absolute` as it needs to float on the right of the blog post.  I setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markfinch/BB3Jm/) to try to show the behavior except that unless I created a div with `overflow:hidden` I couldn't replicate it.  When you hover over the bottom image on the right you can clearly see the clipping.  I found a public site with the BP-Default theme [here](http://www.timersys.com/demos/buddypress/), if you need to take a look at the css.

Since the container div does have `overflow: hidden` I am wondering if it is being inherited.  If that's the case the theme doesn't work properly when I do `overflow: transparent` or remove it entirely.

- Can you find where/why the image is clipped on sidebar div edge?
- Is there a way to bust out using z-index or some other CSS method?
- Is this a bug on Chrome/Safari to clip at the div edge or maybe a bug in Firefox 23 Linux that it doesn't?

Comment: Hi, I can not understand your proper issues. can you tell me in-short way of this issue. so I can solve this.

Comment: Have you looked at the jsfiddle linked above?  Check the lower right image and see the clipping that is the behavior on the actual theme except I can't find an overflow property on it that would cause the clipping.

Comment: overflow: transparent doesn't exists, as far as I know